# Implementing counter when typing variable in array is typed

Tags: c, arrays, counter

ive modified my code to include a counter and it seems to be working but i dont like how its implemented. it seems to count each letter and output the count before the word is finished.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
char C;
char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
int counter=0;
    do
    {
    C = getchar();
    if(memchr(vowels,C, sizeof(vowels)))
        {printf("*\n");
        counter++;
        printf("%i", counter);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("%c",C);
        }



    }while (C!='Q');
}
```

i would like that the output for an input of game would be somethhing along the lines of

```
g*m*
2
```

all im getting now is

```
g*
1m*
2
```

also how could i modify the code so that uppercase letters are also read as lower case?
is there something like isupper or islower in C?

Comment: There is function `toupper()` and `tolower()` in `ctype.h`. You can use them to normalize the characters.

Comment: [islower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/islower/) and [isupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isupper/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the counter to be printed only once, then move it outside of the do-while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    char C;
    char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int counter=0;
    while(1) {
        C = getchar();
        if(C == 'Q') { break; }
        C = tolower(C);
        if(memchr(vowels,C, sizeof(vowels))) {
            printf("*");
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(C == '\n') {
               printf("\n%i\n", counter);
               // reset the vowel counter here (dunno what the actual task is)
               counter = 0;
            } else {
               printf("%c",C);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed a little, should work now. A couple of typos here and there

Comment: Viktor, how does the code print the counter after the edited word?

Comment: Yes, 'true' was another error - I've fixed it and added the counter.

Comment: Judging from the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10836299/335858), this is very likely an untagged homework; letting the OP figure out what's wrong is a lot more instructive than giving him a finished piece of code.

Comment: OK, no more words. Silence is gold.

Comment: these are additional practice questions. im not actually getting graded for them. also the previous question was the actual question. converting to lower and using a counter is for my own knowledge

Comment: how does the counter fall through the blocks? i can't get my head around how its in the else statement.

Comment: Do you want to reset the counter ? Seems logical, but it wasn't in the task description.

Comment: i would be interested in knowing how to do it though.
could you tell me how the counter is at the bottom?

i get the part where when you type white space it will show the counter.
im guessing the braces are confusing me a bit

Comment: seems adding counter=0; where you pointed seems to do the trick

Comment: For me it's not a trick, I just don't know exactly what are you told to do.

Comment: well i was only told to change vowels to *. this is all extra stuff for my knowledge. thanks again Viktor:)